# Howto prevent ntopng causing out of disk space and inodes?

Tags: redis, rrdtool, ntop

I've been trying the ntopng software from http://www.ntop.org/get-started/download on a CentOS box at work to monitor what is happening on our network. The problem I'm having is that I can't find any part of the software that gives an option to delete old data.

The disk usage by this software was so uncontrolled it used 79% of the space and 87% of the inodes on the disk in that server after a few months.

Has anyone seen a solution for having only the most recent xx days or GB of data when using ntopng? Also ensuring it doesn't run out of inodes as well. Can/should I just delete any old files and empty directories in its rrd data directory?

Comment: How quickly did it use up the space ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've encountered a similar problem. One day `df -ih` shows that there is no free inodes on root partition. OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

After some research I found that there is a lot of small .json files in `/var/tmp/ntopng/\*/top_talkers/` which contain information about the most active consumers of traffic.

We don't need that much history (I've seen some files which are 1 year old) so I decided to delete all files older than 2 months:

```
find /var/tmp/ntopng/*/top_talkers/* -mtime +60 -delete
```

Also I’ve added task to the /etc/crontab:

```
@monthly    ubuntu  /usr/bin/find /var/tmp/ntopng/*/top_talkers/* -mtime +60 -delete
```

Now server uses only 55% of inodes.

Comment: So you don't think there's any related meta data that needs updating. Have you noticed any adverse effects from just deleting these files?

Comment: So far, so good. I'm not sure is there any related metadata or not, looks like everything is work as usually.

Comment: For me, the most used directories are the `*/rdd` ones. Do you think it's safe to use the same command (maybe with a longer mtime)?

Answer (score 0):

There is option in Preferences->Timeseries Database.
If you use RRD it is "Old RRDs Terention" and you can specify number of days.
If you use InfluxDB it is "InfluxDB Storage" same idea - number of days.
Also in Preferences->Misc->Databases there is option "Top Talkers Storage" - number of days.

I know the answer is in old question, but I was looking for same information and could not find it. So here it is.